# Debug JavaFx with a tool like FireBug

Tags: css, debugging, javafx

Is there a tool like FireBug (hover and get information about HTML and CSS) to see what is active in a JavaFX scene?

Comment: Try [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/2014/09/announcing-scenic-view-8-0-0/)

Comment: @James_D That's exactly what I was looking for too; want to post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/2014/09/announcing-scenic-view-8-0-0/) – James_D

> Scenic View is a JavaFX application designed to make it simple to
>   understand the current state of your application scenegraph, and to
>   also easily manipulate properties of the scenegraph without having to
>   keep editing your code. This lets you find bugs, and get things pixel
>   perfect without having to do the compile-check-compile dance.